# Overloading an api endpoint

Tags: c#, api

Is it possible to overload an api endpoint?

I would like the endpoint/route to be the exact same thing but the input parameters different. For example....

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("change-xxx")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangeXxx(MyCPModel1 request)
```

And....

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("change-xxx")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangeXxx(MyCPModel2 request)
```

I'm getting an "Multiple actions were found that match the request" error when I try it this way.

Comment: Thanks @gunr2171 but this is using MVC. I'm sure it's a similar solution though?

Comment: Please view the comments on the linked post, where it says that even though the question was asked back in 2009, it's still applicable today with every version of ASP.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer -No, it is not possible to overload a Web API Endpoint. You can't have two endpoints with the exactly same path and verb. The error message "Multiple actions were found that match the request" confirms that.